# Script won't run with correct environmental variables when run with su

Tags: bash, environment-variables, su

I've got a script that I wrote that calls another script but doesn't specify where that script is because it's location should already be in the user's PATH.  By default the user starts in ksh and I've setup the .kshrc file to define all the various directories I need in the PATH variable.  If I run it as the user then it runs fine, but if I try and run it in an su command then it fails.  For example, this won't work

```
su - user1 -c "myscript.sh"
```

I was under the impression that by using the dash with the su command that it would load that users environment.  Is that not correct?  Is there a way around this other then specifying the full path to the other script I'm calling?

Comment: read the `su` man page to see what happens to PATH when you use `-`.

Comment: Looks like PATH doesn't get set the way I thought it did.  I guess I misunderstood what it did.  Is there a flag for su that will set the environment variables like what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1):

> I was under the impression that by using the dash with the su command that it would load that users environment. Is that not correct?

Not quite. It causes the shell to be a "login" shell. What that means is the shell command name is prefixed with a dash. If you type `man ksh` and scroll to the "Invocation" section you'll see that the rules for which "dot" files are read when the shell starts are arcane. Note that by default *~/.kshrc* is only read for interactive shells. Since you are executing a script it won't be an interactive shell. You can force reading .kshrc by using the `-E` flag. But note that in general you should not set env vars like `PATH` in your .kshrc file.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

`su - user1 -c "bash myscript.sh"`

If it doesn't work:

`su - user1 -c "bash /full-path-to-the-file-from-root/myscript.sh"`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to run the script with user1's login environment. Assuming user1's login shell is bash, you can do

```
su - user1 -lc myscrip.sh
```

which passes the `-l` option to bash: see [Bash Startup Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files) for what that means.

Comment: Glenn, that isn't true. A bare `-` and `-l` are equivalent. Both cause the shell to be invoked with a leading dash; e.g., `-bash` which historically how a login shell was invoked. Bash does support `-l` as well but that isn't passed by `su -l`. And, as I noted, a login shell won't source .kshrc or .bashrc unless the shell is also interactive which won't be the case since a script is being run.

Comment: Thanks for the note Kurtis. I did read the su man page, which is why the `-l` is *after* the username, so bash is invoked as `bash -lc ...`. And it is common practice for the user to source the .bashrc within the .bash_profile. I am making assumptions about "user1"s setup.